# Angular Material Stepper: Styling the Active Header

Tags: html, css, angular-material, material-design

I'm using Angular Material Stepper and would like to style the selected header to give it rounded borders with blue background. The css am using now is:

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-header  {
  background-color: #00A9CE;;
  border-radius: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

The css is ok but it applies to all the steps but i only want it to apply to the selected header. There is a class like `.mat-step-icon-selected` to target the selected icon but there is no equivalent to target the selected header.

I want the selected step to look like the following image (the (2) Fruits - it has rounded borders with blue background) and it is only on the selected step.

[image]

Am only interested in the class name that i can use to target the selected header. I tried `.mat-step-header-selected` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The mat-step-header has the role attribute with the value "tab"

```
<mat-step-header role="tab">
```

An element with the role tab also contain so known aria attributes which holds the state of the tab. There is also an aria-selected attribute which indicates wether the mat-step-header is selected or not.

```
<mat-step-header role="tab" aria-selected="true">
```

Now that we know that there is that aria attribute we can go and style selected step-headers:

```
::ng-deep .mat-step-header[aria-selected="true"]  {
  background-color: #00A9CE;;
  border-radius: 32px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 10px;

  & div.mat-step-label.mat-step-label-active.mat-step-label-selected {
      color: #FFF;
  }
}
```

[Additional ressources about aria and role="tab"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Tab_Role)

Comment: I added [aria-selected="true"] to the step-header but now there is a little problem in the UI. The selected step becomes bigger (the width increases) and the other steps become smaller. Before the addition they all have equal widths. Is there a way to fix this. thanks

Comment: can you add a stackblitz example so i could investigate with you and help

Comment: maybe its because of the width: 100% or the font-weight which can affect the rendered size

Comment: You are right. i have removed width: 100% and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: I am trying to change the color of the selected label also to white using this css :

::ng-deep .mat-step-header .mat-step-label-active {
  color: white;
}

but it is not working. Do you have an idea?

Comment: do you mean background color or font color?

Comment: I mean the text (Fruits) inside the header

Comment: Probably it is caused by cascading order and some other css selector has a higher ranking ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity ) just add & div.mat-step-label-active { color: #FFF } inside your previous class if its an scss file. Check my updated answer

Comment: I tried this ::ng-deep .mat-step-header[aria-selected="true"] .mat-step-label-active {
  color: white;
}
 and it works. thanks